# Missing text after using & in textarea when inserting into the database

Tags: php, post, mysqli, get

I have a form where users can add a description with the post they are about to submit. I want the user to add whatever text they want in the textarea. When i was testing i came across this annoying error. Whenever i added & to the sentence the text after that just Disappeared. Example:

Input: This is a good day for a walk & i feel like a million bucks.

Ouput: This is a good day for a walk

This happens when i $_POST or $_GET variables. I thought it was magic_quotes_gpc but i checked in my php.ini file and it is off. I have no idea whats going on. And its not just & but other characters as well. Thank you

Comment: Tried html escapeing?

Comment: Which html escape function are you referring to.

Comment: [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars)

Comment: Show us the relevant code, please

Comment: OK i think that might solve the problem. So once i use htmlspecialchars i can then use htmlspecialchars_decode to go back to characters.

Answer (score 0):

You have to validate & sanitize your input. If you don't, it is extra easy to hack. Look into [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

In your case, you could get by with just:

```
$textareaData = htmlspecialchars($_POST['textarea']);
```

But, ideally, you'll want to:

```
$textareaData = filter_var($_POST['textarea'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. But it still doesn't work. I thought that would work for sure. I tried both options. The same thing still happens